# Can NASCARs ever be found in the Used Car Dealership?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I have already bought about 130 cars from the Used Car Dealership. So far, I have not seen a single car that qualifies for the offline B-Spec Extreme Series NASCAR.

Can NASCARs ever be found in the Used Car Dealership? How are they usually obtained? Is getting gold in the Jeff Gordon NASCAR School special event the only way?

Answer (score 2):

At http://gt5cars.net/cars you can find all the cars that exist in GT5 and the way you can get them.

Seems that no NASCAR car can be bought via the Used Car Dealership, but you can buy them in the new cars store (I know that they are quite expensive).

As you say, another way to get a NASCAR car is via Jeff Gordon NASCAR School.